# Unreal Engine Detour Crowd does not work with Nav Links with different heights?

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine5, navmesh, unreal

I have two nav planes with different height, connected with one nav link (see picture below). I have several pawns with FloatingPawnMovementComponent.

If I use AIController for all the pawns, they can “climb up” the nav link and reach the higher plane. Basically, I believe the movement direction during the nav link is from nav_link_start to nav_link_end (see p1)
[image]

However, if I use DetourCrowdAIController for all the pawns, they do not seem to have any vertical velocity when reaching the nav link. I.e. They only seems to be able to move in the (x,y) plane without any z direction movement, so they cannot climb up the nav link to the higher plane; they only collide to the walls under the nav_link_end (see p2).
[image]

What is the problem?? And how can I make the DetourCrowdAIController to move pawns in z direction as well?

FYI: my pawn BP setting is very simple, I attached here for reference, but all the settings are the same.
[image]